# Losing control on fancybox after postback on partialview

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, fancybox

I am loading partialview from fancybox. partialview has `Form=Post`, once I submit form and I need to show results on same fancybox `<div>`.

But return result loading full view and I am loosing control on fancybox after submit.

view load fancybox

```
<a href="#" onclick="display_dialog()"><strong>Email</strong></a>

@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/fancybox")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/jquery.fancybox.css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script type="text/javascript">
    function display_dialog() {
        $.fancybox.open({
            href: '/ContactSubmission/',
            type: 'ajax',
            padding: 0,
            openEffect: 'fade',
            openSpeed: 'normal',
            closeEffect: 'elastic',
            closeSpeed: 'slow',
            minWidth: 'auto',
            minHeight: 'auto',
            helpers: {
                title: {
                    type: 'float'
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
}
```

### index.cshtml

```
 @using System.Web.UI.WebControls
 @model SPE.ContactSubmissionForm.Models.Contact

   <div id="result"></div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = 
             "multipart/form-data", @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
     {
        //html controls
           <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-offset-5">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
     }
```

javascript

```
$(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('form').submit(function () {

        if ($(this).valid()) {
            $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                contentType: attr("enctype", "multipart/form-data"),
                type: this.method,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (result) {
                     $('#result').html(result);

                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
```

### ContactSubmissionController .cs

```
public class ContactSubmissionController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var contact = new Contact
        {
            Countries = Context.GetCountries()
        };

        return PartialView(contact);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Contact contact)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (contact != null)
            {

            }
        }

        return Content("Thanks", "text/html");
    }
}
```

How to stay in the same fancybox after I post back?